# Find increasing and decreasing values in a column SNOWFLAKE ,SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake like below, and wanted to add new column represents if that row is increasing or decreasing based on the next row!

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 |
| 2 | 70 |
| 3 | 70 |
| 4 | 70 |
| 5 | 70 |
| 6 | 71 |
| 7 | 72 |
| 8 | 73 |
| 9 | 73 |
| 10 | 73 |
| 11 | 74 |
| 12 | 74 |
| 13 | 74 |
| 14 | 74 |
| 15 | 73 |
| 16 | 72 |
| 17 | 73 |
| 18 | 72 |
| 19 | 72 |
| 20 | 72 |
| 21 | 72 |
| 22 | 71 |
| 23 | 71 |
| 24 | 72 |
| 25 | 72 |

Expected Output:

| id | value | DESIRED OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 | INCREASING_ID1 |
| 2 | 70 | INCREASING_ID2 |
| 3 | 70 | INCREASING_ID3 |
| 4 | 70 | INCREASING_ID4 |
| 5 | 70 | INCREASING_ID5 |
| 6 | 71 | INCREASING_ID6 |
| 7 | 72 | INCREASING_ID7 |
| 8 | 73 | INCREASING_ID8 |
| 9 | 73 | INCREASING_ID9 |
| 10 | 73 | INCREASING_ID10 |
| 11 | 74 | INCREASING_ID11 |
| 12 | 74 | INCREASING_ID12 |
| 13 | 74 | INCREASING_ID13 |
| 14 | 74 | INCREASING_ID14 |
| 15 | 73 | DECREASING_ID15 |
| 16 | 72 | DECREASING_ID16 |
| 17 | 73 | INCREASING_ID17 |
| 18 | 72 | DECREASING_ID18 |
| 19 | 72 | DECREASING_ID19 |
| 20 | 72 | DECREASING_ID20 |
| 21 | 72 | DECREASING_ID21 |
| 22 | 71 | DECREASING_ID22 |
| 23 | 71 | DECREASING_ID23 |
| 24 | 72 | INCREASING_ID24 |
| 25 | 72 | INCREASING_ID25 |

Comment: @RaymondNijland AM USING SNOWFLAKE!

Comment: You are showing INCREASING in your desired out put when a value doesn't change at all.  Is that the logic you need applied?

Comment: there is also a question of what to do for the first value, is it increasing because the "prior value is zero" thus a first value of -1 would be a DECREASE, OR is the first value truth, and the defiant prior state is INCREASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a two step process. First step, find the direction of the lag: increasing, decreasing, or null if neither direction. Second step, if the current direction for a row is null, refer back to the last non-null value (null previously defined as no change in direction):

```
with DIRECTION as
(
select   ID
        ,VALUE
        ,case
            when ID = 1 then 'INCREASING'
            when VALUE > lag(VALUE) over (order by id) then 'INCREASING'
            when VALUE < lag(VALUE) over (order by id) then 'DECREASING'
            else NULL
         end as OUTPUT
from T1
)
select   ID
        ,VALUE
        ,case when OUTPUT is null then
            lag(OUTPUT) ignore nulls over (order by ID) || '_ID' || ID
         else OUTPUT || '_ID' || ID
         end as OUTPUT
from DIRECTION
;
```

Comment: thanks so much, could you please check this up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73412037/find-the-interval-for-each-user-increasing-decreasing-using-snowflake

Comment: the `|| '_ID' || ID` can occur outside the case, to reduce repetition, and `null || 'a'` is null

Answer (score 0):

So this is the same answer is Greg's, I have just written it verbosely to show the workings:

firstly a CTE for data:

```
with data(id, value, DESIRED_OUTPUT) as  (
    select * from values
        (1, 70, 'INCREASING_ID1'),
        (2, 70, 'INCREASING_ID2'),
        (3, 70, 'INCREASING_ID3'),
        (4, 70, 'INCREASING_ID4'),
        (5, 70, 'INCREASING_ID5'),
        (6, 71, 'INCREASING_ID6'),
        (7, 72, 'INCREASING_ID7'),
        (8, 73, 'INCREASING_ID8'),
        (9, 73, 'INCREASING_ID9'),
        (10, 73, 'INCREASING_ID10'),
        (11, 74, 'INCREASING_ID11'),
        (12, 74, 'INCREASING_ID12'),
        (13, 74, 'INCREASING_ID13'),
        (14, 74, 'INCREASING_ID14'),
        (15, 73, 'DECREASING_ID15'),
        (16, 72, 'DECREASING_ID16'),
        (17, 73, 'INCREASING_ID17'),
        (18, 72, 'DECREASING_ID18'),
        (19, 72, 'DECREASING_ID19'),
        (20, 72, 'DECREASING_ID20'),
        (21, 72, 'DECREASING_ID21'),
        (22, 71, 'DECREASING_ID22'),
        (23, 71, 'DECREASING_ID23'),
        (24, 72, 'INCREASING_ID24'),
        (25, 72, 'INCREASING_ID25')
)
```

then two selects, as the two LAG's cannot co-exist at the same level:

```
select *
    ,lag(change)ignore nulls over(order by id) as lag_change
    ,nvl(change, lag_change) || '_ID' || id as final_answer
    ,DESIRED_OUTPUT = final_answer as is_same
from (
    select *
        ,lag(value)over(order by id) as lag_v
        ,case 
            when lag_v is null then 'INCREASING'
            when value<lag_v then 'DECREASING'
            when value>lag_v then 'INCREASING'
        end as change
    from data
)
order by 1;
```

| ID | VALUE | DESIRED_OUTPUT | LAG_V | CHANGE | LAG_CHANGE | FINAL_ANSWER | IS_SAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 | INCREASING_ID1 | null | INCREASING | null | INCREASING_ID1 | TRUE |
| 2 | 70 | INCREASING_ID2 | 70 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID2 | TRUE |
| 3 | 70 | INCREASING_ID3 | 70 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID3 | TRUE |
| 4 | 70 | INCREASING_ID4 | 70 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID4 | TRUE |
| 5 | 70 | INCREASING_ID5 | 70 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID5 | TRUE |
| 6 | 71 | INCREASING_ID6 | 70 | INCREASING | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID6 | TRUE |
| 7 | 72 | INCREASING_ID7 | 71 | INCREASING | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID7 | TRUE |
| 8 | 73 | INCREASING_ID8 | 72 | INCREASING | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID8 | TRUE |
| 9 | 73 | INCREASING_ID9 | 73 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID9 | TRUE |
| 10 | 73 | INCREASING_ID10 | 73 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID10 | TRUE |
| 11 | 74 | INCREASING_ID11 | 73 | INCREASING | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID11 | TRUE |
| 12 | 74 | INCREASING_ID12 | 74 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID12 | TRUE |
| 13 | 74 | INCREASING_ID13 | 74 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID13 | TRUE |
| 14 | 74 | INCREASING_ID14 | 74 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID14 | TRUE |
| 15 | 73 | DECREASING_ID15 | 74 | DECREASING | INCREASING | DECREASING_ID15 | TRUE |
| 16 | 72 | DECREASING_ID16 | 73 | DECREASING | DECREASING | DECREASING_ID16 | TRUE |
| 17 | 73 | INCREASING_ID17 | 72 | INCREASING | DECREASING | INCREASING_ID17 | TRUE |
| 18 | 72 | DECREASING_ID18 | 73 | DECREASING | INCREASING | DECREASING_ID18 | TRUE |
| 19 | 72 | DECREASING_ID19 | 72 | null | DECREASING | DECREASING_ID19 | TRUE |
| 20 | 72 | DECREASING_ID20 | 72 | null | DECREASING | DECREASING_ID20 | TRUE |
| 21 | 72 | DECREASING_ID21 | 72 | null | DECREASING | DECREASING_ID21 | TRUE |
| 22 | 71 | DECREASING_ID22 | 72 | DECREASING | DECREASING | DECREASING_ID22 | TRUE |
| 23 | 71 | DECREASING_ID23 | 71 | null | DECREASING | DECREASING_ID23 | TRUE |
| 24 | 72 | INCREASING_ID24 | 71 | INCREASING | DECREASING | INCREASING_ID24 | TRUE |
| 25 | 72 | INCREASING_ID25 | 72 | null | INCREASING | INCREASING_ID25 | TRUE |

and thus the final SQL can be:

```
select id, value
    ,nvl(change, lag(change)ignore nulls over(order by id)) || '_ID' || id as final_answer
from (
    select id, value
        ,lag(value)over(order by id) as lag_v
        ,case 
            when lag_v is null then 'INCREASING'
            when value<lag_v then 'DECREASING'
            when value>lag_v then 'INCREASING'
        end as change
    from data
)
order by 1;
```

which is the same as Greg's other than I have used the implicit NULL result in the inner CASE, and I used a [NVL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl.html) instead of CASE in the outer SELECT, a [COALESCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html) could also be used here.

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you please check this up
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73412037/find-the-interval-for-each-user-increasing-decreasing-using-snowflake